# Is download Public S3 AWS Buckets illegal?

Tags: internet, cfaa

**What are S3 Buckets?**

An Amazon S3 bucket is a public cloud storage resource available in Amazon Web Services' (AWS) Simple Storage Service (S3), an object storage offering. Amazon S3 buckets, which are similar to file folders, store objects, which consist of data and its descriptive metadata.

ref https://searchaws.techtarget.com/definition/AWS-bucket

**Are they private?**

By default, all S3 buckets are private and can be accessed only by users that are explicitly granted access. ... Restrict access to your S3 buckets or objects by: Writing AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user policies that specify the users that can access specific buckets and objects.

ref https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secure-s3-resources/

**What tools are required to access s3 buckets?**

There are many tools that are free to download. AWS even has a CLI tool that you add your free amazon credentials to and can access their data from your home machine.

**Question:**

If a company were to accidentally configure an S3 Bucket to be public, is downloading their data illegal?

Comment: If someone forgets to lock their front door one day, is it OK to go in and take things?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I've heard that argument, however this isn't a house. This is something that's made public and available to the public on a public communication system regardless if that's intentional or not. I'm not sure we can compare it to a house.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I think a better analogy would be, your company has a phone system that when you call it, it starts reading off usernames and passwords. Is it illegal for you to call that number and write that information down?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch also, one more note, there are many instances of public s3 buckets that are intentionally left public for the public to access. So there's that faucet of this problem as well.

Comment: #1 How are houses, apartments, and cars not in the public realm? Just because something is accessible to the public doesn't mean you can open the door at any given time. The door designates the boundary between public and private. #2 That's a false analogy; that's not the default mode for a phone system; it is misconfigured, and if intentionally, that's a different question. #3 "Intentionally left public for the public to access"? Why would that be illegal? And that's "facet," not faucet.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch the S3 bucket being set to public isn't a vulnerability or a misuse of the system. It's literally how it was designed to be used. The phone system example is exactly what's happening from a technical standpoint. It's a public system, free to use, being used in the manner it was intended to be used. The question is really the data and that onus is on the owner of the s3 bucket to decide what they want to make public. If they accidentally make too much public, I'm not sure that's the fault of the person using the system to download it

Comment: @BlueDogRanch also to answer your question about houses, those are private property. So regardless if you leave it unlocked or not, the law still identifies it as private property. Whereas, data is still a gray area

Comment: Ownership of data is a gray area?!? Hahahaha....

Comment: @BlueDogRanch If I put my password on a poster board, put it in my house and you can see it through the window, is it illegal for you to look at it and remember it? I still own my password, it's still my data but now you know it. I feel like you're painting with a broad brush. There's lots of edge cases here.

Comment: I'm not saying there are not edge cases. My point in commenting is to get you to think about your question. Your password in the house window analogy is ridiculous; you're conflating two analogies; and you have given access to your data. "Ownership of data" is a different question, one that you don't address in your original question. If that's your question, edit your question.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I appreciate your opinion but I actually came to the law.stackexchange to see documented legal cases that make this a little clearer, not gather opinions. From what I can tell CFAA doesn't cover accessing publicly accessible systems that a reasonable person can access in a reasonable manner. S3 Buckets that are public facing can be accessed by anyone. No special skills are needed. Is there case law that says otherwise?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=CFAA

Comment: @BlueDogRanch thank you for the link. I think you should post it as an answer so the community can weigh in on your input as well.

Comment: My point (partialy) is that your question may be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Cars are meant to be driven, and their doors are meant to open. Does that make legal to get in an unlocked car and drive it away, simply because it is now *"something that's made public and available to the public on a public [transportation] system regardless if that's intentional or not"*? Don't be absurd.

Comment: @Nij if the car is marked "Public" and put some place where other publicly accessible cars are, that are commonly accessed by the public, knowingly or not, then yes, I'd say it's what any reasonable person would say is legal. Once again though, I'm trying to find cases that prove that it's illegal, not form an argument to steal company data